# Radio button group, requiring one be picked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know this question has been asked in some form or another, but wanted to see if anyone had an answer. I can't seem to figure it out.  I need to put an asterisk next to the label here and then have the user choose one of the options. We are using the validate plug in. I have tried a bunch of things so far to no avail.  Any ideas?

```
//Radio button group that needs one choice to validate, else show an error

<div class="field" >
    <div class="label-cont">
    <label for="null" class="am_radio field-label"> What is the main purpose of this email?</label>
</div>
   <ul title="What is the main purpose of this email?" class="radiolist">
    <li>
        <input name="attribute_service_copy_purpose_value" id="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_0" type="radio" class="amRadio" value="Visibility"><label class="radiolabel" for="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_0">Visibility</label></li>  

          <li>
             <input name="attribute_service_copy_purpose_value" id="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_1" type="radio" class="amRadio" value="Drive Traffic"><label class="radiolabel" for="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_1">Drive Traffic</label></li>

               <li><input name="attribute_service_copy_purpose_value" id="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_2" type="radio" class="amRadio" value="Brand Enhancement"><label class="radiolabel" for="am_attribute_service_copy_purpose_value_2">Brand Enhancement</label></li>
                    </ul>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see jquery validate anywhere in your code so assuming that is just an option. You can use HTML5's native form validation to make one of the radio button required when they all (in a group) has the same name.

Here is an example:

```
<form action="http://some.randompageonthe.net">  
  <p>  
    <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="a" required> A</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="b" required> B</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="c" required> C</label><br>   
  </p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uyrkpgLa/)

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a PHP form that renders HTML so I can't use that way unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I was facing the same scenario.
A simple solution is that you can set one of the radio button as 'checked' by default.

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="a" checked> A</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="b" > B</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="r" value="c" > C</label><br>
```

After this you will not need to put validation on it.